# Add legend for various stat_ellipse

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with various data ellipses (stat_ellipse) such that I have varied the alpha level. How can I add a legend to the plot to correspond to the various ellipses (with color and alpha level)?

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(RColorBrewer)

colors <- brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Blues")
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1, color='navy') +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.1, color=colors[1], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.2, color=colors[2], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.3, color=colors[3], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.4, color=colors[4], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.5, color=colors[5], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.6, color=colors[6], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.7, color=colors[7], size=1.1) +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.8, color=colors[8], size=1.1)  +
   stat_ellipse(level=0.9, color='navy', size=1.1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Could you add a fully [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that other people can run?

Comment: added the packages, so everything is reproducible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is possible with `stat_ellipse`. Here is a solution. It consists in computing the ellipses with the `car` package and then using `geom_path`.

```
library(car)
levels <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.2)
ell <- dataEllipse(faithful$waiting, faithful$eruptions, draw = FALSE, 
                   levels = levels, segments = 200)

library(purrr)
paths_list <- imap(ell, function(mat, level){
  cbind(mat, level=as.numeric(level))
})
paths <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, paths_list))
paths$level <- as.factor(paths$level)

ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, color='navy') +
  geom_path(aes(x=x, y=y, group=level, color=level), data=paths, size = 2)
```

[image]